# Expected bounds on universal hashing

Tags: hash, language-agnostic

I am sure this is a simple problem to work out, but I don't see an obvious solution... If I have a hash table with *m* bins and hash into this *n* < *m* keys, what is the probability that no bin receives more than *k* hash-keys. I'm trying to figure out how many rehash operations I should expect if I fill up a table to load *n* / *m* and then rehash until I see no more than *k* collisions in any bin (obviously with *k* > *n* / *m*).

Comment: You should take a look at birthday problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem assuming you have an efficient hash.

Comment: `until I see no more than k collisions in any bin (obviously with k > n / m).` The upper bound is a bad metric, IMHO. Instead, you could use the *average* (or expected) *chain length*, which relates to the amount of  work to retrieve one element. For n==m, this is just below 1.5, given a reasonable hash function.

Comment: The reason I am interested in the probability of more than k collisions is that I want to rehash when a bin is above a constant, and I hope that the probability after rehashing is small enough that I get a geometric series so I can expect a finite number of rehashes. For using the birthday problem, I guess I need the keys to be uniformly distributed. Is having a universal hash distribution enough to apply it?

Comment: I guess math.stackexchange.com is a better place for this question.

Answer (score 1):

With uniform distribution, this is the same as throwing balls into bins, which has been studied in ["Balls into Bins - A Simple and Tight Analysis"](http://www.dblab.ntua.gr/~gtsat/collection/scheduling/Balls%20into%20Bins%20A%20Simple%20and%20Tight%20Anal.pdf) from M. Raab and A. Steger.

This is a bit related to [cuckoo hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing), but here you just use one hash function.

As this is stackoverflow.com, I give you a simulation program that can be used to verify your formula. According to this, it also depends on the number of balls / buckets, and not just on the the average number of balls per bucket.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
    for (int k = 1; k < 4; k++) {
        test(10, 30, k);
        test(100, 300, k);
    }
}

public static void test(int ballCount, int binCount, int k) {
    int rehashCount = 0;
    Random r = new Random(1);
    int testCount = 100000000 / ballCount;
    for(int test = 0; test < testCount; test++) {
        long[] balls = new long[ballCount];
        int[] bins = new int[binCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < ballCount; i++) {
            balls[i] = r.nextLong();
        }
        // it's very unlikely to get duplicates, but test
        Arrays.sort(balls);
        for (int i = 1; i < ballCount; i++) {
            if (balls[i - 1] == balls[i]) {
                throw new AssertionError();
            }
        }
        int universalHashId = 0;
        boolean rehashNeeded = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < ballCount; i++) {
            long x = balls[i];
            // might as well do y = x
            long y = supplementalHashWeyl(x, universalHashId);
            int binId = reduce((int) y, binCount);
            if (++bins[binId] > k) {
                rehashNeeded = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (rehashNeeded) {
            rehashCount++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("balls: " + ballCount + " bins: " + binCount +
            " k: " + k + " rehash probability: " + (double) rehashCount / testCount);
}

public static int reduce(int hash, int n) {
    // http://lemire.me/blog/2016/06/27/a-fast-alternative-to-the-modulo-reduction/
    return (int) (((hash & 0xffffffffL) * n) >>> 32);
}

public static int supplementalHashWeyl(long hash, long index) {
    long x = hash + (index * 0xbf58476d1ce4e5b9L);
    x = (x ^ (x >>> 32)) * 0xbf58476d1ce4e5b9L;
    x = ((x >>> 32) ^ x);
    return (int) x;
}
```

Outputs:

```
balls: 10 bins: 30 k: 1 rehash probability: 0.8153816
balls: 100 bins: 300 k: 1 rehash probability: 1.0
balls: 10 bins: 30 k: 2 rehash probability: 0.1098305
balls: 100 bins: 300 k: 2 rehash probability: 0.777381
balls: 10 bins: 30 k: 3 rehash probability: 0.0066018
balls: 100 bins: 300 k: 3 rehash probability: 0.107309
```

Comment: I guess my problem is if the “balls and bins” probabilities also work with the universal hashing condition which is not as strict as random distributions over bins. I am interested in this for some lecture notes I am writing where I want to cover universal hashing and rehashing. I will also write about cuckoo hashing, but that is for the next chapter. I wanted to cover the simpler rehashing idea first. What I want to know is the relationship between how many rehash operations I expect as a function of the maximum collisions I get per bin.

Comment: I can work this out if keys are put in bins with a uniform distribution, but if I have x != y => Pr[h(x)=h(y)] <= O(1), I am not so sure. I am really only interested when the bound is 1 or 2, but I need at least 2 to handle the universal hashing construction that uses bit masking instead of modulus.

Comment: I have Rasmus Pagh, who is one of the two authors of cuckoo hashing, proof reading the notes, so I am sure he will catch it if I get something wrong :) I’m just trying to do some back-of-the-envelope calculations for a simple setup where you rehash if you get more than a fixed constant balls in the same bin.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean with "universal hashing construction that uses bit masking instead of modulus". I'm quite sure you can use bit masking _or_ modulus (or something else) for universal hashing? For back-of-the-envelope calculations I think the formula above should be fine... but I think it would be better to write a small simulation program, is this what you are looking for? For mathematical stuff you are better of with math.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can create universal families using modulus that gives you Pr[h(x)=h(y)] <= 1/m for a random function h but I think that the masking construction only gives you Pr[h(x)=h(y)] <= 2/m. I have asked at the CS stack exchange now, https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/93352/bounds-on-probe-lengths-and-number-of-rehashes-with-universal-hashing -- will try math.stackexchange later, if I don't get an answer there.

Comment: For simulations, I am a little worried about it being too dependent on the input. I will never see pathological examples if I sample random keys, and in such cases, universal hashing is not necessary. They give guarantees against adversaries so I want to understand what the exact bounds there are... but I'll try to work at the math some more. Thanks for all your comments, though, they are very helpful.

Comment: I added a simulation program, and hope it is useful. I wouldn't be too worried about the simulation not be realistic, I would be more worried about picking the wrong formula (as I originally did, it seems). I'm also a bit interested in this topic, and will follow this question.

Comment: Thanks for the program, but doesn't it draw random keys? If the keys are truly uniformly distributed over the bins, I think I understand how the collision probabilities work. If I pick a random hash function that only guarantees me that for two non-identical keys I have a bound *k/m* for some constant *k*, I am not sure if the same math applies. Even if *k* is 1, so Pr(h(x)=h(y)) <= 1/m for a random function h and two inputs x != y. That is the guarantee I have for the distribution of hash functions, but I think it is weaker than mapping to random bins.

Comment: I have probably been too lazy in defining the problem, and for that I am sorry.

Comment: Sure the program draws random keys, but the distribution and probabilities should be the same as with real data. Except if you use a really bad hash function. And even if you do - with a supplemental hash function (as in the simulation above), you should be fine.

Comment: The point of using a universal hash family is to avoid bad hash functions using randomisation. If the hash function already gives me a uniform distribution, I don't need to draw hash functions at random. If I only require that the probability of colliding two non-identical keys is bounded, for a random function, then I don't get a random distribution of keys. The function h is random, but x and y are not. If picking a random h would give random h(x) and h(y), then I would have the same distribution as in your simulation, but that is a stronger requirement.

Comment: This all sounds very theoretical (sorry... I don't fully understand what you wrote). Sure, many hash functions in practise don't have a uniform distribution at all. Which is somewhat needed by (practical) hash table implementations. That's why supplemental hash functions are used in practise (as I did in the simulation above). Even those don't protect against attacks (eg. hash flooding), and for _that_ some implementations (like the default Java hash map implementation) have additional protection. But I'm not sure how is that related to your original question...

Comment: No, the problem is rather theoretical. It isn't something I would worry about in practice. I would just love to know how the behaviour is for something I'm writing on.